# Flutter ListView snapshot error on Chrome web

Tags: ios, flutter, google-chrome, listview

Currently i am fetching some data from the internet and parse it to a List for later showing it up on a ListView.
During the running on iOs mobile and macOs it shows perfectly, tho during the running on Chrome web it pops out an snapshot error during the fetchData.

```
List<Supply> parseSupplies(String responseBody) {
    final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<Supply>((json) => Supply.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

Future<List<Supply>> fetchSupplies() async {
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://datadis.es/api-private/api/get-supplies'),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Accept": "application/json",
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ${globals.getToken()}',
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // return token
    print("Respuesta OK");
    return parseSupplies(response.body);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    print("Respuesta NOT OK");
    throw Exception('Failed to fetch supplies');
  }
}
```

There is where i make the request call and after that I show it up in the suppliesPage widget

```
class _suppliesPageState extends State<suppliesPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Mis Suministros'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Supply>>(
        future: fetchSupplies(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('An error has occurred!'),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return SupplyList(supply: snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SupplyList extends StatelessWidget {
  const SupplyList({super.key, required this.supply});

  final List<Supply> supply;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: refresh,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: supply.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = supply[index];

          print(item.cups);

          return Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.lightbulb, color: Colors.orange),
                  title: Text(
                    item.cups,
                    style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(item.address),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Text(
                      'Suministro con direccion: ${item.address} ${item.municipality} ${item.province}'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text('Consultar consumos'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Can someone explain me why does it show the data on iOs but not during Chrome?
[Result on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzRmW.png)
[Result on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mf2dW.png)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most probably blocked by CORS policy. Where is your app running? Different domain then API? Does API allow cross-origin access?

Comment: Hi i will try tomorrow about that CORS (never heard about it). The app i'm just debugging on ios simulator and Chrome. Not sure about last question.